# Метод вывода записей с определенным тегом

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Всем привет. Есть блог в котором записи хранятся в MSSQL. У каждой записи есть коллекция тегов.
Вот **модель одной записи**:

```
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Heading { get; set; }
    public string PageTitle { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string FeaturedImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string UrlHandle { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishedDate { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
```

И **модель тега:**

```
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }
```

Список все записей на главную страницу блога вывожу с помощью этого метода:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<BlogPost>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await blogDbContext.BlogPosts.OrderByDescending(p => p.PublishedDate).Include(x => x.Tags).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Все хорошо работает, все меня устраивает. Но, теперь мне необходимо создать страницу всех записей с определенным тегом.
Например все записи с тегом "Футбол".
Как мне необходимо написать метод?

Пробовал через .Containts особо не получается. Что мне надо передать в этот метод, id этого Тега?

Comment: `.Where(x=>x.Tags.Any(tag => tag.Name == "Футбол"))`? Не знаю правда как это EF примет.

Comment: Спасибо, так работает. Разумеется у меня множество тегов, и чтобы для каждого мне не делать, надо передать в метод параметр `(Guid id)`, а в методе: `.Where(x=>x.Tags.Any(tag=>tag.Id == id))` ?

Comment: Да, если поиск по id, то так. `Any` можете заменить на `Contains`, но вы сказали, что не работает, это уже смотрите там сами.